# Asynchronous Testing Issue: Unit Test Assertions Executing Before Asynchronous Code Completes

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, junit, kotlin-coroutines

I'm encountering a peculiar issue while writing JUnit tests for an asynchronous code path involving Kotlin coroutines. I'm trying to test a scenario where I launch an asynchronous document processing operation, but the assertions in my test seem to fail because they execute before the asynchronous code completes.

**Code Under Test:**

Here's the relevant code snippet that I'm trying to test:

```
@POST
@Path("/process")
override fun processDocumentsAsync(): Response =
    documentService.launchAsyncDocumentProcessing().respond()

// DocumentService
private val scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)

fun launchAsyncDocumentProcessing(): Either<Failure, Unit> =
    Either.catch {
        scope.launch { processDocuments() } // This is a suspend function
    }.fold({ throwable ->
        ServiceFailure.ServerError("Failed to launch process", throwable).left()
    }, { Unit.right() })
```

**Test Scenario:**

Here's a simplified version of my JUnit test:

```
@BeforeEach
fun setUpRequest() {
    Dispatchers.setMain(StandardTestDispatcher())
}

@Test
fun `async processing test`() {
    runTest(timeout = 10.seconds) {
        // Given: Setting up mocks and other required objects
        
        // When: Executing the asynchronous method
        val response = RestClient.processDocumentsAsync()

        // Then: Assertion for the asynchronous method
        response.asClue {
            it.statusCode shouldBe HttpServletResponse.SC_NO_CONTENT
        }
    }

    // Problem: The following assertion fails
    WiremockUtils.verifyDocumentsArchivedCount(2)
}
```

**Issue:**

The issue I'm facing is that the assertion WiremockUtils.verifyDocumentsArchivedCount(2) at the end of the test is failing consistently. It seems like the asynchronous operations triggered by RestClient.processSdosAsync() are not fully complete by the time the assertions are executed. However, if I introduce a sleep before the assertion, the test passes.

I've thoroughly gone through the documentation at https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-test/kotlinx.coroutines.test/run-test.html, but unfortunately, I haven't been able to resolve my problem using the information there.

**Questions:**

1. How can I ensure that my assertions execute only after the asynchronous operations inside processDocumentsAsync() are completed?
2. Is there a proper way to wait for asynchronous operations to complete in my JUnit tests without introducing arbitrary sleep times?
3. Are there any best practices or techniques in Kotlin coroutines or JUnit that I should be using to address this kind of scenario?